# Json.NET custom JsonConverter being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a generic class, whose children I want to serialize with the value of only one of its attributes.

To this end, I wrote a custom `JsonConverter` and attached it to the base class with the `JsonConverter(Type)` Attribute - however, it does not ever seem to be called. For reference, as shown in the example below, I am serializing a `List<>` of the object using the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json()` method.

If there is an altogether better way of achieving the same result, I'm absolutely open to suggestions.

***Example***

**View function**

```cs
public JsonResult SomeView()
{
    List<Foo> foos = GetAListOfFoos();
    return Json(foos);
}
```

**Custom JsonConverter**

```cs
class FooConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This never seems to be run");
        // This probably won't work - I have been unable to test it due to mentioned issues.
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (value as FooBase<dynamic, dynamic>).attribute);
    }

    public override void ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This never seems to be run either");
        return objectType.IsGenericType
            && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FooBase<,>);
    }
}
```

**Foo base class**

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public abstract class FooBase<TBar, TBaz>
    where TBar : class
    where TBaz : class
{
    public TBar attribute;
}
```

**Foo implementation**

```cs
public class Foo : FooBase<Bar, Baz>
{
    // ...
}
```

**Current output**

```cs
[
    {"attribute": { ... } },
    {"attribute": { ... } },
    {"attribute": { ... } },
    ...
]
```

**Desired output**

```cs
[
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json() doesn't work with Json.NET - it uses [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)  that doesn't know anything about your Json.NET stuff. If you still want to use System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json() call you should do something like [this](http://wingkaiwan.com/2012/12/28/replacing-mvc-javascriptserializer-with-json-net-jsonserializer/). Also change `WriteJson` to this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, ((dynamic)value).attribute);
}
```

I think this should make your code work.

Comment: I was under the impression it did, though wouldn't be surprised if I were wrong - perhaps it was something else that pulled Json.NET as a dependency. Thanks for the article, I'll give it a read.

Comment: ASP.NET WebApi uses JSON.NET as json serializer, but ASP.NET MVC doesn't. I know it's confusing.

Comment: Ah, that would have been it.

Comment: Can confirm that this was the underlying issue. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 13):

What happened to me was, I added the `using` statement automatically as suggested by Visual Studio. And by mistake added `using System.Text.Json.Serialization;` instead of `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

So I was using `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterAttribute` on the target class. Which is (correctly) ignored by Json.Net.

Comment: This happened to me as well (in the converter class)

Comment: Exactly what happened to me too.

Comment: This had me and my colleague stumped for the best part of two hours!!

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says:
To apply a JsonConverter to the items in a collection use either JsonArrayAttribute, JsonDictionaryAttribute or JsonPropertyAttribute and set the ItemConverterType property to the converter type you want to use.

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Maybe that will help.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks. Spent ages trawling through the docs, but didn't really know what I was looking for.